Pandas MultiIndex Rolling Group by
Pandas has some very strange group by behavior with Multi_indexing. I don't understand why one of these sites is not being calculated but when called alone works perfectly fine.
Consider the following code
all_data['rolling_avg_supply_temp'] = all_data.groupby(level=0).rolling('1h',on='ts')['supplytemp'].mean()
all_data['rolling_avg_supply_temp'].groupby(level=0).describe()




site
count
mean
std
min
25%
50%
75%
max




1A1
22130.0
21.698209
0.588990
14.611525
21.521668
21.837078
22.001139
23.345806


2B5
22533.0
21.952604
0.535339
18.900000
21.828639
21.976729
22.110053
25.985087


3B8
9515.0
22.060124
0.427317
19.500000
21.822788
22.004277
22.226354
24.400361


3B9
19234.0
21.810098
0.686575
19.530944
21.657984
21.966606
22.142692
23.987056


VC1A1
0.0
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN



The VC1A site just doesn't get a rolling average applied in the function call.
However consider this function call ON THE SAME dataset
all_data.loc["VC1A1"].rolling('1h',on='ts')['supplytemp'].mean().describe()




Statistic
Value




count
14400.000000


mean
21.492677


std
0.406032


min
20.152830


25%
21.345195


50%
21.430232


75%
21.755384


max
22.265454



There is no mixing of datatypes for reference here is the info on the dataset
all_data.info()




Metadata
Value




Total Entries
5,456,561


Memory Usage
654.1+ MB


MultiIndex From
('1A1', Timestamp('2024-04-07 17:00:00.431000+0000', tz='UTC'))


MultiIndex To
('VC1A1', Timestamp('2024-04-17 09:29:28.405000+0000', tz='UTC'))


Total Columns
11






Column Index
Column Name
Dtype




0
sn
object


1
ts
datetime64[ns, UTC]


2
maxcellt
float64


3
mincellt
float64


4
supplytemp
float64


5
hvac_status_c1runstat
float64


6
hvac_status_c2runstat
float64


7
hvac_status_bypassdamp
float64


8
hvac_sensor_heatcurrent
float64


9
hvac_sensor_avgspacetemp
float64


10
timediff
timedelta64[ns]




Can you provide a reproducible example of the df that are yoU using (namely: all_data)?
